# Using Pandas to split by unique values and append as new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have several Excel files generated from some remote sensing data that I am trying to sort in Pandas. I have three columns, distance along transect, velocity, and date of image. Here is a subset

```
Distance (m)       Velocity (m/day)        Date
0.000000            0.0763   20080815_20080826
4.972390            0.0763   20081031_20081111
9.944780            0.0763   20080815_20080826
14.917169            0.0763  20081031_20081111
19.889559            0.0763  20081031_20081111
24.861949            0.0761  20081031_20081111
29.834339            0.0761  20081031_20081111
13180.925174         0.0124  20080928_20080103
13185.912173         0.0123  20080928_20080103
13190.899172         0.0123  20080815_20080826
13195.886172         0.0122  20080928_20080103
```

I would like to use the *Date* column and split it for each unique value. I think I can do this with the groupby command. However I would also the output formatted so that the three columns for each individual image data are appended as new columns. The end result will be an excel file I can share with non-technical colleagues that looks something like:

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l58Eq.png)

I would be grateful for any hints on how to do this in pandas.

Comment: And how do you want to reduce the results after grouping by `Date`? Ex: take the `sum`? Also please add a sample of your desired output, its always clearer

Comment: I actually don't want to reduce the results, I want to output it as an excel file that is easier to read for my non-technical colleagues.

I will update the desirec output

Comment: groupby is for aggregation, you should sort by date instead in my opinion

Comment: Thanks for the response. And do you know of a way of having each date as a seperate set of columns?